# what does set_include_path() do?

Tags: php

according to the php manual:

> Specifies a list of directories where the require, include, fopen(), file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions look for files. The format is like the system's PATH environment variable: a list of directories separated with a colon in Unix or semicolon in Windows.

i dont understand why you should specify the directory ?

for example i saw this code

```
<?php
    defined("DS") || define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR);

    defined("ROOT_DIR") || define("ROOT_DIR", realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS."..".DS));

    defined("CLASSES_DIR") || define("CLASSES_DIR", "classes");

    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPERATOR, array(
         realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.CLASSES_DIR.DS),
         get_real_path()
    )));

?>
```

why add the CLASSES_DIR to the include path ? cant you already do something like require("classes/example.php") ?

Comment: When doing `require("classes/example.php")` you are trying to get a file relative to the [current working dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php), which can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the include path you do not need to explicitly specify the full path to your files anymore since php then has some options where to look after i.e. your 'example.php'. Assuming you had a php file called 'exampleClass.php' inside your 'DOCUMENT_ROOT/classes' directory and an index.php located directly under your DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
<?php
     set_include_path(DOCUMENT_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes');
     // Note that exampleClass.php is not located in the same directory as this index.php
     require('exampleClass.php');
?>
```

But I would like to add that in the depicted example there are probably better alternatives of organizing and structuring your project to avoid 'require(/hope/this/path/is/the/right/one.php)' statements. E.g. by using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/de/language.namespaces.php) in combination with [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Plus one for autoloading. PSR-4 and Composer are just *so good*.

Comment: I absolutely agree it's priceless

Comment: ty for the answer i fully understand the logic behind set_include_path()

Comment: this code actually comes from a php tutorial that im following and the author is using both set_include_path and autoload, so whats that all about ?

Comment: would you please post the link to that tutorial?

Comment: its a premium tutorial from udemy, https://www.udemy.com/ecommerce-website/ ps: i checked the link and it seems the you can watch section 2 for free thats where my problem is, Autoloader and Configuration File(Continue)

Comment: I'm really trying to understand what they are doing but without seeing the code everything I could write know would be guesswork. I can definitely say that it sounds confusing to me so far. Sorry.